# Accessing enum arguments outside of constructor?

Tags: java, enums

I'm having trouble trying to fill a static map with values from arguments of an enum. Example of what I'm trying to say here:

```
public enum LettersAndNumbers {
     A(1, 2),
     B(2, 3);

     private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> numbers = new HashMap<Integer, Integer();

     private LettersAndNumbers(int numberone, int numbertwo) {}

      // Somehow put arguments "numberone" and "numbertwo" into map

     public static Integer getNumberTwo(int numberone) {
          return numbers.get(numberone);
     }
}
```

Is there a way to access these variables in a static block, or elsewhere outside of the constructor?  I have been looking around for a while now, but I could find nothing on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. But I guess that you want to put all of enums into HashMap for getting when needed. So you can try putting in Constructor of enum: numbers.put(numberone, numbertwo);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the `numberone` and `numbertwo` in your `enum` as *fields*. Then you can use a *static initialization block* to iterate the `values()` and store them in your `Map`. Something like,

```
public enum LettersAndNumbers {
    A(1, 2), B(2, 3);
    private int numberone;
    private int numbertwo;
    private static Map<Integer, Integer> numbers = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (LettersAndNumbers lan : LettersAndNumbers.values()) {
            numbers.put(lan.numberone, lan.numbertwo);
        }
    }

    private LettersAndNumbers(int numberone, int numbertwo) {
        this.numberone = numberone;
        this.numbertwo = numbertwo;
    }

    public static Integer getNumberTwo(int numberone) {
        return numbers.get(numberone);
    }
}
```